# ngx-bootstrap - styling dropdown-menu-right without !important? Angular 6

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, angular6, ngx-bootstrap

I have a row in which there is gonna be dropdown and pagination moved to the right side. 
Can I style "dropdown-menu-right" (the ul element) to move e.g. 100px from the right, so there is pleace for pagination at the edge of the page, 0px from the right? I mean, I know it is possible if I add !important to my style but I would probably rather to avoid that. But I don't see another way as bootstrap gives it's styling inline.

Other thing is that I can't change the width of dropdown-menu, even with !important... It always has the initial bootstrap width. If I give "li" element 50px width, then the rest of the pleace is just filled with white background.

It would be great if ul stack to the button/a href element.

```
<span class="itemsPerPage" dropdown (onShown)="onShown()" 
   (onHidden)="onHidden()" (isOpenChange)="isOpenChange()">

   <a href id="itemsPerPage" dropdownToggle (click)="false"
        aria-controls="basic-link-dropdown">Number of products
        <span><label class="m-0">{{ limit }}</label><span 
        class="glyphicons glyphicons-chevron-down"></span></span>
   </a>

   <ul id="basic-link-dropdown" (placement)="top" *dropdownMenu class=" 
       dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right"
       role="menu" aria-labelledby="itemsPerPage">

       <li *ngFor="let limitOnPage of limitsOnPage">

           <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{ limitOnPage }}</a>
       </li>
   </ul>

</span>


.itemsPerPage
{
margin-left: auto;
height: fit-content;

& > a
{
    color: $col-g;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 34px;

    & > span
    {
        font-weight: 500;
    }
}

& > ul
{
    right: 50px;
    left: auto;
    & > li
    {
        min-width: 50px;
        width: fit-content !important;
        background-color: red;

        & > .dropdown-item
        {
            padding: 0;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post your html and css ?

Comment: Ok, I posted. Have you any idea?

Comment: take a look to :host and ::ng-deep